# SuperOneClick freezes when I try to root my Sony Xperia Tipo Dual

Tags: rooting, sony-xperia-tipo

SuperOneClick freezes when I try to root my Sony Xperia Tipo Dual.

I did unlock the bootloader.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the method of rooting used by SuperOneClick has been blocked on the Tipo Dual. I haven't seen the phone on any of the compatability lists for SuperOneClick. There are other methods you can use, and for the Tipo Dual I quickly found [UnlockRoot](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2120435) and a guide on how to root from XDA-Developers. Use at your own risk.